# display data from database in a specific order: php or mysql?

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

I have a table for phone numbers:

```
phone:
phoneID (PK)
peopleID (fK)
countrycode
areacode
phonenumber
extension
phonetype //EDIT!!! (sorry forgot this in first post)
```

Every person can have max 4 phone numbers: company, fax, home, mobile.

I have an edit form. The edit form pulls data from the DB and populate the form.
This code to pull data:

```
$stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM phone WHERE peopleID=?");
if ( !$stmt ) {
    die(printf("Error: %s.\n", mysqli_stmt_error($stmt) ) );
}
else if ( !$stmt->bind_param('i', $peopleID) ) {
    die(printf("Error: %s.\n", mysqli_stmt_error($stmt) ) );
}
else if ( !$stmt->execute() ) { 
    die(printf("Error: %s.\n", mysqli_stmt_error($stmt) ) ); 
} else {
    $resultaddress = $stmt->get_result();

    while($row = $resultaddress->fetch_assoc()) {
        $phoneID_array[] = $row['phoneID'];  
        $phonetype_array[] = (isset ($row['phonetype']) ? $row['phonetype'] : "");
        $countrycode_array[] = (isset ($row['countrycode']) ? $row['countrycode'] : "");
        $areacode_array[] = (isset ($row['areacode']) ? $row['areacode'] : "");
        $phonenumber_array[] = (isset ($row['phonenumber']) ? $row['phonenumber'] : "");
        $extension_array[] = (isset ($row['extension']) ? $row['extension'] : "");
    }   
}
```

and this to populate the form:

```
for ($i = 0; $i < 4; $i++) {
    echo 'Phone<input type="text" name="type[]" id="" value="' . (isset ($phonetype_array[$i]) ? $phonetype_array[$i] : "company") . '"/>';
    echo '<input type="text" name="countrycode[]" id="" size="3" maxlength="3" value="' . (isset ($countrycode_array[$i]) ? $countrycode_array[$i] : "") . '"/>';
    echo '<input type="text" name="countrycode[]" id="" value="' . (isset ($areacode_array[$i]) ? $areacode_array[$i] : "") . '"/>';
    echo '<input type="text" name="number[]" id="" value="' . (isset ($phonenumber_array[$i]) ? $phonenumber_array[$i] : "") . '"/>';
    echo '<input type="text" name="extension[]" id="" value="' . (isset ($extension_array[$i]) ? $extension_array[$i] : "") . '"/><br>';                

}
```

The form now displays:

company  000 000 1234567

home     000 000 1234569

(no empty fields to eventually enter new numbers)

PROBLEM:

I would like to display phone numbers always in the same order:
Let's say I only have company and home numbers in DB, the edit form should look like

company : 000 000 1234567

fax  :    empty fields to fill

home  :   000 000 1234569

mobile :  empty fields to fill

It could probably be done with associative arrays, but I don't know how :(

Thanks for your help!

EDIT: After reading all the answers and comments here, I understood that it was a better design to have a dedicate table phonetype, and use a foreign key in the phone table. Thinking that this was a completely different scenario, I asked this other question [mysql left join not return all left table row](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34916051/mysql-left-join-not-return-all-left-table-row)
Thanks again to everybody who took the time to help me.

Comment: Consider using an `ORDER BY` clause in your query? Also, where are you storing the phone type in the database ?

Comment: @Maximus2012 the issue is probably that two of the records don't exist, so the empty fields always appear last

Comment: @RobbieAverill you're right. In that case, the user should probably have a second table for phone type and then try iterating through that table first.

Comment: It's not clear what' do you want because your title asks for something, but then the problem you explain (if I got it well) talks about something else

Comment: So how are you indicating that one of those rows is a Company or Home phone number? There is nothing in the table to indicate that

Comment: @RiggsFolly sorry, look at my edit pls

Comment: @Gavriel Thank,feel free to edit the title, I thought it was something that needed to be done in php

Comment: @codeispoetry, I added mysql tag, but actually it's hard to rephrase the question, because the things I could write instead would already indicate the knowledge of the answer I gave, which obviously you didn't have when you asked it :)

Comment: @Graviel Title modified! Hope is better :)

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to add another field to the phone table:

```
'phonetype' ENUM('company','fax','home','mobile')
```

and the query:

```
SELECT phone.* FROM people 
    LEFT JOIN phone ON phone.peopleID=people.peopleID 
WHERE people.peopleID=? AND phone.phonetype='company'
UNION 
SELECT phone.* FROM people 
    LEFT JOIN phone ON phone.peopleID=people.peopleID 
WHERE people.peopleID=? AND phone.phonetype='fax'
UNION 
SELECT phone.* FROM people 
    LEFT JOIN phone ON phone.peopleID=people.peopleID 
WHERE people.peopleID=? AND phone.phonetype='home'
UNION 
SELECT phone.* FROM people 
    LEFT JOIN phone ON phone.peopleID=people.peopleID 
WHERE people.peopleID=? AND phone.phonetype='mobile'
```

Now you'll get 4 lines, some of them might be nulls

Comment: @Gravel Thanks Gravel, I'm testing it now. 2 Little questions: 1) if I already have the field phonetype, how do I set it as ENUM? 2) Do you think for phone types, it is better to have a separate table? Thanks!

Comment: it doesn't matter what type it is. If it's an integer, then instead of phone.phonetype='company' use: phonetype=0, etc.

Comment: Worth knowing what you're getting into with an ENUM: http://komlenic.com/244/8-reasons-why-mysqls-enum-data-type-is-evil/

Comment: sorry Gavriel, where do I enter `'phonetype' ENUM('company','fax','home','mobile')` ? It gives me an error

Comment: You don't have to, I wrote that before you remembered you already have that field, though you still hold the secret about it's type. Just use the one you already have.

Comment: @Gavriel Yes, I saw the article after you suggested to us the ENUM. What would be the alternative? A separate table phonetype and a join questy as Miken32 suggested in the comments?

Comment: @codeispoetry, come on! I told you to use your existing phonetype field. I also told you I can't read your mind, nor the code you don't post here. If you need more help please update the question with the sql create table (including types) and also add the "people" table or whatever you call it that peopleID refers to

Comment: @Gavriel All righ, I see. I will add a phonetype table and try to do a join. If I won't b able, I will post another question and put a link here. Thanks again for your help!

Comment: Here is the new situation, hope is better :) [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34916051/mysql-left-join-not-return-all-left-table-row)

Comment: @Gavriel I must be mistaken, but I saw in your comment you said that using a dedicate phonetype table is not a good solution? May I ask why? I thought that everybody here is going in that direction... Thanks!

Comment: This was the simplest answer when I knew only what was in your original question (no mention of phonetype). I never said a foreign key is not a good solution

Comment: Thanks Gavriel, I asked just to be sure I'm on the right path!

Answer (score 1):

I could think of a dozen ways to improve this; most obvious would be a separate phone numbers table in the database. But, for easiest drop-in code replacement, you can just make it a single array keyed by type:

```
/* Make an empty array with empty values for each phone type */
$emptyphone = array(
    "countrycode"=>"",
    "areacode"=>"",
    "phonenumber"=>"",
    "extension"=>"",
);
$phones = array(
    "company"=>$emptyphone + array("phonetype"=>"company"),
    "fax"=>$emptyphone + array("phonetype"=>"fax"),
    "home"=>$emptyphone + array("phonetype"=>"home"),
    "mobile"=>$emptyphone + array("phonetype"=>"mobile"),
);

/* Now fill in the values you do have */
while($row = $resultaddress->fetch_assoc()) {
    $phones[$row["phonetype"]] = $row;
}

/* Now you can loop through them with a simple foreach */
foreach($phones as $phone) {
    echo 'Phone<input type="text" name="type[]" id="" value="' . $phone["phonetype"] . '"/>';
    echo '<input type="text" name="countrycode[]" id="" size="3" maxlength="3" value="' . $phone["countrycode"] . '"/>';
    echo '<input type="text" name="countrycode[]" id="" value="' . $phone["areacode"] . '"/>';
    echo '<input type="text" name="number[]" id="" value="' . $phone["phonenumber"] . '"/>';
    echo '<input type="text" name="extension[]" id="" value="' . $phone["extension"] . '"/><br>';                
}
```

Comment: Thanks Miken! What do you mean by separate table for phone numbers? A separate table for every type? Like: table_companyphone, table_homephone... etc?

Comment: Sorry, meant phone types. Then phonetype in your existing database becomes a foreign key and the join would result in empty values for any types that were missing. Similar to the other answer, but I didn't want to suggest database changes, not sure if this is live code or not.

Comment: Thanks miken, it's not live yet, so I could add a foreign key. I can still add a phonetype  table. What would you write the code with the join in that case `$stmt = $conn->prepare("NEW SQL WITH JOIN");` . Sorry I'm still new at this!