# mysql left join not return all left table row

Tags: php, mysql

I have 2 tables

```
phonetype:
phonetypeID (PK)
phonetyepe

phone:
phoneID (PK)
peopleID (fK)
phonetypeID (fK)
areacode
number`
```

For a specific peopleID I would like to return all the phonetypes and if the peopleID has the number diplay it, if not empty. Something like:

```
phonetype    phonetypeID    areacode    number
company      1              111         11111
fax          2
home         3              222         222222
mobile       4
```

Here is my prepared statement:

```
$stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT *
FROM phonetype
LEFT JOIN phone
ON phonetype.phonetypeID=phone.phonetypeID
where phone.peopleID = ?; 
");
if ( !$stmt ) {die(printf("Error: %s.\n", mysqli_stmt_error($stmt) ) );}
else if ( !$stmt->bind_param('i', $peopleID) ) {die(printf("Error: %s.\n", mysqli_stmt_error($stmt) ) );}
```

But this way I only have

```
phonetype    phonetypeID    areacode    number
company      1              111         11111
home         3              222         222222
```

What am I doing wrong? PS this is my first join!!
Thanks!!

EDIT (This question follows this other question [[display data from database in a specific order: php or mysql?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34911866/display-data-from-database-in-a-specific-order-php-or-mysql][1]) . After reading the answers of Gravel, Robbie Averill, Maximus2012 and Miken32  I understood that it was a better design to have a dedicate table phonetype, and use a foreign key in the phone table. Thinking that this was a completely different scenario, I asked this new question. If anybody thinks this is a duplicate and there is a way to join the 2 question, I will do it. Thanks again to everybody who took the time to help me.)

Comment: Can you please be more clear? can you please place your both the tables data!?

Comment: Hard to be sure without the data, but just replacing `where` with `and` looks like it could fix things.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [display data from database in a specific order: php or mysql?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34911866/display-data-from-database-in-a-specific-order-php-or-mysql)

Comment: @Gavriel Gavriel, please see my edit. Hope it explains my intensions. Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In your query;

```
SELECT *
FROM phonetype
LEFT JOIN phone
ON phonetype.phonetypeID=phone.phonetypeID
where phone.peopleID = ?
```

...the `WHERE` clause with a condition on the rightmost table will remove all rows where the rightmost table has no value, negating the `LEFT JOIN`.

What you most likely want is to add the condition to the `LEFT JOIN`'s `ON` clause instead, allowing the empty values of `phone` to still show up;

```
SELECT *
FROM phonetype
LEFT JOIN phone
  ON phonetype.phonetypeID=phone.phonetypeID
 AND phone.peopleID = ?
```

Comment: yup! it works! Thanks!! And thank you for explaining why it works!

Answer (score 2):

use AND instead of WHERE

```
SELECT *
FROM phonetype
LEFT JOIN phone
ON phonetype.phonetypeID=phone.phonetypeID
AND phone.peopleID = ?
```

Comment: Just to add some explanation. The `WHERE` filter the results after the `JOIN`, that is why you only get the rows where match the ID. To see what I mean try `WHERE phone.peopleID = ? AND phone.peopleID IS NULL` and you will get same result as SIDU